# SQL Server :Remove duplicate records but be able to choose which record to keep by specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have problem and just can't find the right solution.
Hope you can help me.

I have a table the looks like this:

```
ID  Date      description     location
1  2012-12-01   low              A
1  2012-12-01   low              A
1  2012-12-01   low              B
2  2012-12-01   High             A
3  2012-12-01   Low              C
```

The result should look like this

```
ID  Date      description     location
1  2012-12-01   low              B
2  2012-12-01   High             A
3  2012-12-01   Low              C
```

I hope you could help me.

Comment: Have you tried `group by`?

Comment: How you identified that B should be chosen and not A? Is it alphabetical order?

Comment: Also can there be only 2 locations A and B or there can be any number of locations and you want to choose a specific one based on some logic?

Comment: In my case there are three locations A,B,C

Comment: I have updated my question to make it more occurred

Comment: which column determine which rows to keep and with which logic ? Seems you got a bunch of answers, and everyone is guessing, since this has not been specified

Comment: The location column is the determent column

Comment: What determine which location to choose from ? Highest alpha numeric value perhaps ? Location doesn't sound like a column that could determine the order of the rows

Comment: It's a varchar and I have there categories there A, B and C and it's not for order determination, it's for choosing which rows will stay and which will be deleted

Comment: Your question is still unclear. How do you know that 'B' is the correct value to retain for ID #1, and not 'A'?  What would you do if #1 also had a 'C' value available?  Edit your question with a full explanation of how you choose which value from 'Location' should be in your resultset.

Answer (score 1):

A general method to prioritize rows is to use `row_number()` with a `case` statement.

In your case, this would seem to be:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, description
                                order by location desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: your answer is not correct with the new data in the question. I don't see how you can answer the question even now with the addtional information

Comment: @t-clausen.dk . . . The modified code works for the current version.  I'm not sure if that is what the OP intends.

Comment: I don't think the PARTITON should have included description,  As the question stands now, it isn't necessary, but it is the right idea. And a bad example in the test data in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID,Date,description,MAX(location) as location
FROM tableName
GROUP BY ID,Date,description
```

Comment: please be careful with MAX over character columns! if you have an excel-like order A-Z, AA, AB and so on this won't work. The MAX value of `AA` and `B` is `B` on SQL Server!

Answer (score 0):

Using the DISTINCT to eliminate duplicates rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,Date,description, location
FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select just duplicated records (to remove them) with last location use a query like this:

```
;WITH t AS (
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Date, description 
                              ORDER BY location DESC) As seq
    FROM yourTable)
SELECT ID, Date, description, location -- change this line to `DELETE` for removing
FROM t
WHERE (seq > 1);
```

[[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48a07/12)

You can preview the result of `yourTable` before removing by this query:

```
SELECT ID, Date, description, location
FROM (SELECT *, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Date, description 
                                 ORDER BY location DESC) As seq
      FROM yourTable) dt
WHERE (seq = 1);
```

[[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48a07/10)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT ID,Date,description,location
FROM tableName
GROUP BY ID,Date,description,location
Having count(location) = 1
```